# What sense does the Fourier transform make if it diverges all the time?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

The Fourier transform of a signal, $x(t)$ is defined as:

$$X(\omega) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty x(t) e^{-i \omega t} dt$$

This is supposed to pull out cosines and sines from the signal. So let's give it the simplest possible case. Let $x(t) = \cos(\gamma t)$

It seems now that the the integral above, even for this $x(t)$ doesn't converge. If you make the limits really large instead of infinite, then sure you can see it becoming a large number for $\omega = \gamma$ and not so large otherwise. But the definition itself seems to be useless by virtue of just diverging all the time.

What am I missing?

Comment: to be rigorous, this definition only makes sense if the function is absolutely integrable. You also correctly noted, that if $x(t)=\cos(\gamma t)$ then it is not absolutely integrable so this definition doesn’t make sense. The more general definition relies on the notion of a *tempered distribution*, and with that notion, you can still make sense of Fourier transforms.

Comment: Assuming $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ then

$$X(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_t[x(t)](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(\gamma t)\,e^{-i \omega t}\,dt=\pi\, \delta(\omega-\gamma)+\pi\, \delta(\omega+\gamma)\tag{1}$$

where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta function and

$$x(t)=\mathcal{F}_{\omega}^{-1}[X(\omega)](t)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\pi\, \delta(\omega-\gamma)+\pi\, \delta(\omega+\gamma))\, e^{i t \omega}\,d\omega =\cos(\gamma  t)\tag{2}$$

Comment: @StevenClark - this is very helpful. Would really appreciate it if you could add this as an answer and flesh out some of the details.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ then consider the Fourier transform

$$X(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_t[x(t)](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(\gamma t)\,e^{-i \omega t}\,dt=\pi\, \delta(\omega-\gamma)+\pi\, \delta(\omega+\gamma)\tag{1}$$

where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta function and the inverse Fourier transform

$$x(t)=\mathcal{F}_{\omega}^{-1}[X(\omega)](t)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\pi\, \delta(\omega-\gamma)+\pi\, \delta(\omega+\gamma))\, e^{i t \omega}\,d\omega=\cos(\gamma  t)\tag{2}$$

where the integral in formula (2) above can be evaluated as

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\pi\, \delta(\omega-\gamma)+\pi\, \delta(\omega+\gamma))\, e^{i t \omega}\,d\omega=\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{i \gamma t}+e^{-i \gamma t}\right)=\cos(\gamma  t)\tag{3}$$

which follows from the relationship

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(\omega-a)\, f(\omega)\,d\omega=f(a)\tag{4}$$

Comment: But how do you get the Dirac delta functions in equation (1)? If I plug it into any integral solver, the integral is deemed "failed to converge".

Comment: @RohitPandey The Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$ is not a normal function but rather a generalized function (distribution), so the integral in formula (1) above only converges in a distributional sense. I'll attempt to clarify my answer above when I find a bit more time.